# Where does an ASP.NET code-behind file execute? (client or server)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind, execution

My friend who is an experienced developer (but not familiar with .NET) asked me where ASP.NET code-behind code is actually executed; on the server or on the client.  My assumption was that it is executed on the client and therefore compiled to JavaScript, since methods in your code-behind file will respond to client-side events such as selecting a dropdown list, which do not cause a postback.

What I'm really looking for is a more intimate understanding of how/where the code in a code-behind file is executed in relation to the rest of the application.

Comment: The code behind will be executed on the server.  You can read on msdn asp.net life cycle http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yeah...what @DanHunex said.

Comment: Here's a decent post that covers this topic in a broad sense: http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net_server_doc/developer/adf/pagepost_clientcall.htm

Answer (score 6):

The Codebehind always executes on the Server. That's the reason, its also called `ASP.NET WebForms`. When the web page is executed, below is what happens in a nutshell.

1. The Web Page gets flushed as a HTML form
2. Web Controls get flushed as HTML input elements with necessary Javascript
3. The Javascript remains as-is (unless injected dynamically)

The next question ... **how does ASP.NET Server Side know what events i performed on Client side to execute appropriate events on server side?**

The answer is, ASP.NET converts each web control to one or more html elements & names them uniquely so that it can get back the name of the HTML element generating the event(s) and act accordingly. It uses `ViewState` (apart from various other uses) to make sure the html controls names are not tampered in the roundtrip.

The link given in the other answer should help you understand more.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: .NET code compiles into assemblies (.DLL) files which live and execute on the server.

JavaScript executes on the client (generally, see [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)) and .NET code runs on the server. These two technologies communicate with either other via HTTP Request/Reponses.

When a page is first requested from a server, it runs through all of the .NET code and the response from the server is HTML to be rendered. This HTML may contain links to other files, such as script or stylesheet files. Once the server sends the response it has nothing to do with the page anymore.

Client side languages such as JavaScript can communicate with the server via full page post backs, partial postbacks (UpdatePanels, gross), or AJAX. They send new requests to the server and the server responds with new page/HTML/data/etc.

See [this article](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net_server_doc/developer/adf/pagepost_clientcall.htm) for more information about client/server interactions with web applications.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163675.aspx

Code behind file execute on server side.
ASP.NET could easily generate all of the control variable declarations in addition to the rendering methods from the .aspx file as a partial class which could then be merged with your simplified codebehind class. This is exactly how Windows Forms works in the .NET Framework 2.0. All of the designer-generated code is placed into a sibling partial class which is then merged with your application logic and event handlers into a single Form-derived class, creating a clean separation between machine-generated code and developer code without resorting to inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The code behind file are executed on server. There are lot of resources available on internet. One of them could be this [link](http://odetocode.com/articles/406.aspx)

Hope you got your answer